# Problem with Google Cloud Run connecting to my cloudbuild file

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, cloudfiles

This is my first time dealing with the Google Cloud with my nodejs with WebSocket program, so I definitely expect a lot of errors to show up along the way as I learn how the process works. Right now, I am stuck at an error that seems to be an issue with the cloud run getting information from the cloudfile when Cloud Run is trying to deploy.
"ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1".

I just use the default cloudbuild that the Google Cloud Run documents have. [cloudbuild documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run)
This cloudfile is in the root directory of the project with the Dockerfile that the docker program generated for my project.

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  # Docker Build
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/game-gossip-409604/gamegossip-server/gamegossip', '--network=cloudbuild', '.']

  # Docker Push
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/game-gossip-409604/gamegossip-server/gamegossip', '--network=cloudbuild']

  # Entrypoint, timeout and environment variables
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: 'gcloud'
    timeout: 240s
    args: ['compute', 'instances', 
           'create-with-container', 'my-vm-name',
           '--container-image', 
           'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/game-gossip-409604/gamegossip-server/gamegossip']
    env:
      - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_REGION=us-central1'
      - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=us-central1-a'
```

Dockerfile

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=20.10.0

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=package-lock.json,target=package-lock.json \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm ci --omit=dev

USER node

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD node server.js
```

The program/Dockerfile work perfectly when running locally, so I assume it is just an issue of how the files are transferred to the Google Cloud Run.
I have tried looking at other people's post that have the same error message, but for each case it seems the solution is highly individualized. I figured with mine it is just a simple file or line of code that I am missing, but I am unable to find out what that missing piece is. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you mount all this file? Is it not easier to copy them? Anyway, can you check the Cloud Build logs, you should have more detail on the root cause. Share them with us.

Comment: You state Cloud Run, but you are deploying to Compute Engine (COS). Edit your question to clearly define the environment and problem including the Cloud Build logs.

Comment: [Build Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tboj8OprQOBl4yMldBFtwUbl9sTrQmjG/view?usp=sharing). Here are the build logs. It looks like maybe BuildKit triggered an error, but I do not add buildkit anywhere in my docker. In the Cloud Build History both of the  deploy and push steps appeared to work, but it failed on the build step. Thank you for your time. @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: The copy option worked @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you for your help!